# Provider not found exception

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, provider

We have a cover page that has two buttons. One leads to the Contractor's login and registration page, and the other button leads to Hirer login and Registration.
In order to check whether a user is already logged into the app, we are using a wrapper.dart which contains the following code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    print(user);
    enter code here
    if (user == null) {
      return Authenticate();
    } else {
      return Home();
    }
  }
}
```

This is our code snippet for contractorwrapper. We have a similar one for hirerWrapper as well. We are getting this error:

> /flutter (23750): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
> I/flutter (23750): The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building ContractorWrapper(dirty):
> I/flutter (23750): Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this ContractorWrapper Widget

Comment: add your main.dart or app code code

Comment: Please add the code where you build your MaterialApp(...)

Answer (score 1):

```
   class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return   MultiProvider(
    providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
  create: (context) => User())],
  child: MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          title: Text("First appbar"),
        ),
        body: Text("content")),
       ),
     );
 }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the class `User` extends the class `ChangeNotifier` you have to add a `ChangeNotifierProvider` above your `MaterialApp`, which defines how the `User` is created.

[Here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) you can find a great guide how to integrate the Provider into your app.

This would look like the following:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => User(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
              title: Text("First appbar"),
            ),
            body: Text("content")),
      ),
    );
  }
}

//just an example
class User extends ChangeNotifier {
  String _name;

  set name(String value) {
    _name = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  String get name => _name;
}
```

If something is unclear - Feel free to ask.